# Refactoring a somehow generic method

Tags: c#

I am using a certain method of mine over and over again. Therefore, I tend to import this class to all of my projects, where I have to access the IsolatedStorage of a Windows Phone-Device.

But, it doesn't really seem elegant to me. 
Take a look:

```
public static Object getFileContent (String filename, String returntype)
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            Object returnobj = new Object();
            List<String> list = new List<String>();
            String r;

            IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = isf.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);

            if (returntype.Equals("list"))
            {
                while ((r = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    list.Add(r);
                }
                returnobj = list;
            }
            else if (returntype.Equals("string"))
            {
                r = reader.ReadLine();
                returnobj = r;
            }

            fileStream.Close();
            reader.Close();

            return returnobj;
        }
```

My main issue is the paramter `returntype`. It's a obviously a string.
I'd like to have it as the type directly. But that didn't work on my last attempt.

Also, when I use this method, like for instance:

```
string random = (string) MyFavClass.getFileContent("randomFile","string");
```

I have to convert the return type of that method once again, before I can use it.

Comment: what happens when you change the signature to have a Return Type of `string` can you not change the method to be `dynamic`

Comment: @DJKRAZE I don't think that can be done, since return obj can be of type List<string> or string.  It may be possible according to the IDE, but it would be a really bad idea to hide a List<string> inside a string.  This could also cause runtime exceptions.

Comment: What version of C# are you using? Can you consider using `dynamic`?

Comment: `TheGreatCO` I appended `dynamic` while noticing his Type Declarations inside his code structure..

Comment: Is readonly, forwardonly access to the file contents sufficient? Is it desired to treat strings and List<string> identically? If yes to both I may have an even better implementation for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write two methods: `getFileContentAsString` and `getFileContentAsList`. You're not getting any benefit of genericness here if you can only support exactly two types.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the best way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the strategy pattern if you're going to have an arbitrary amount of return types.

```
public static T GetFileContents<T>(String filename, Func<StreamReader, T> readMethod)
{
    // initialize stuff

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(...))
    {
        return readMethod(reader);
    }
}

public static string ReadStreamAsString(StreamReader reader)
{
    return reader.ReadLine();
}

public static List<string> ReadStreamAsList(StreamReader reader)
{
    var list = new List<string>();

    while ((r = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        list.Add(r);
    }

    return list;
}
```

And to use it:

```
string myString = GetFileContents("foo.txt", ReadStreamAsString);

List<string> myList = GetFileContents("bar.xml", ReadStreamAsList);
```

My generics are probably off, but hopefully it conveys the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I would try to do something like this:

```
public static T getFileContent (String filename, Func<StreamReader, T> process)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        Object returnobj = new Object();
        List<String> list = new List<String>();
        String r;

        IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = isf.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);

        try{
            return process(reader);
        }
        finally{
            fileStream.Close();
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

I'm sure this is error-prone as I have it, but the idea is to pass in a converter function that will handle whatever type you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1. Readonly, forward only acces is all that's required from the List; and
2. It is desired to treat the results of both possibilities identically in the application code.

Then he following would work:

```
  public abstract class MySequence : IEnumerable<string> {
    protected string Filename { get; private set; }

    public MySequence(string filename) {
      Filename = filename;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return this.GetEnumerator(); }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() {
      using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) 
      using (var stream = isf.OpenFile(Filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
        return GetEnumerator(reader);
      }
    }
    protected abstract IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator(StreamReader reader);
  }
  public class MyListSequence : MySequence, IEnumerable<string> {
    public MyListSequence(string filename) : base(filename) {}
    protected override IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator(StreamReader reader) {
      while (! reader.EndOfStream) yield return reader.ReadLine();
    }
  }
  public class MyStringSequence : MySequence, IEnumerable<string> {
    public MyStringSequence(string filename) : base(filename) {}
    protected override IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator(StreamReader reader) {
      yield return reader.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

Usage would be like this:

```
  foreach (var s in (new MyListSequence("fred"))) { Console.WriteLine(s); }
  foreach (var s in (new MyStringSequence("fred"))) { Console.WriteLine(s); }
```

A particular advantage of this mechanism, when ti applies,is that no storage needs to be allocated for the List; eaxh text line is simply read and returned by the iterator.